# OneDrive (fB) syncing gets stuck at the last bit and kills my upload bandwidth

Tags: sync, onedrive

This is about OneDrive for business.

For a few days now, most of my uploads on OneDrive have the behavior shown in the screen capture (link below): it uploads fine until the last bit. Then gets stuck, the file doesn't show from the web portal, can't be shared, and above all use my whole upload bandwidth. I tried to leave it for a whole night but it's uploading, I have no clue what it could be uploading actually. The same byte again and again?

I insist this is for most of my new file syncs, whatever their size or their location.

I tried to reset onedrive (there's a button for that in the settings).
I tried to unlink, link again.
I tried to use a preview version to force the installation of another version.
Of course I have rebooted many times.
I am far away from the 255 characters limit.

I can't see a trigger for that, can't remember of a Windows update, or even a change on my personal network. I'm using the latest Windows 10 build (Windows Update doesn't show any available update).

I can hardly work because of this, has anyone any idea how I could fix this?

Here is what it looks like: https://prout.ovh/images/2021/04/14/0892306f50b0b4e8d17f989e1bd176e4.png

edit : this looks even weirder: https://prout.ovh/images/2021/04/14/0e41d589262b0ef2444c85f9cec983b8.png

**I was able to "unlock" the sync by changing the upload speed limit, changing "Automatic adjustment or no limit" to "limited". Then I started seeing the screen right above.**

Feels like a real bug but I find it strange I'm the only person on the web with this (I did a lot of search on Google before posting here).

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check whether the files could be uploaded successfully on OneDrive Online?

Please check whether there is enough space for the disk where the local OneDrive folder is located, such as C drive.

It is recommended to remove some **large files** from OneDrive, then re-upload some files to have a check.
(Please before removing files, you need to back them up first.)